# Redirect URL while keeping original

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect a url like `example.com/contact/` to `example.com/contact.php` without the visitor viewing the redirection. So, the browser should keep `example.com/contact/`.

I know how to  do simple redirect with .htaccess, but the problem is that I can't use absolute paths for different reasons so the page does not load correctly.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^contact/?$   contact.php  [NC]
```

Any alternatives?

Comment: Is your application in subfolder so you cannot use absolute path?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this additional rule:

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(.+?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|ico|tiff|css|js))$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Could you explain this a little more further? I'm really bad at .htaccess. I tried to add it to what I already have (orignal post) but this isn't working so far.

Comment: Ok let's get it in working state then I will add proper explanation based on the final answer. Did you place this rule in `DocumentRoot` OR in a sub directory?

Comment: @anubhava In the `DocumentRoot` - example.php/.htaccess/

Comment: OK then can you tell me full URL which is not working. Is `http://domain.com/contact` not working? Is `contact.php` also at the same level as .htaccess

Comment: The redirect is working, like in my example. But I have the same problem with including the files. They are relative so don't load correctly. And I can't change it to absolute.

Comment: You mean .js, .css and images?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an easier way using PHP:

```
<?php 
//add some params
$_GET['param1'] = value1;
$_GET['param2'] = value2;
//the actual page you wish to redirect to
include "/var/www/page.php";
?>
```